# Chaining dependent jQuery deferred with progress, fail and then

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm somewhat new to js promises and working on a legacy system using jQuery 1.7.1
while trying to clean up some callbacks mess, I seems to be creating a new one.
Thanks in advance for your help!

1. Created Utils for accessing webapi service over ajax.  I am using
   jQuery's *Deferred()* instead of *new Promise()*, but at the end I am
   returning a *Promise*, which upon success/error gets
   resolved/rejected.

   ```
   var Utils = (function () {
   // private
   var _timeout = 3000;
   // ...

   // public
   return {
       getHeartBeat: function(id) {
           var deferred = $.Deferred();
           deferred.notify('Getting a heartbeat ... ' + id);
           $.ajax({
               url: URLS.getHeartBeat,
               type: 'GET',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   deferred.resolve(id, data);
               },
               error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   deferred.reject(id, makeError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown));
               },
               timeout: _timeout
           });
           return deferred.promise();
       }
   };
   // ...
   ```

   })();

   2. The need is to request a new heartbeat AFTER coompletion of the previous one:

      function testHeartBeatChaining() {

      ```
      PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(1)
      // Hearthbeat 1
      .progress(function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);
      })
      .fail(function(id, err) {
          console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
      })
      .then(function(id, beat) {
          console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
          return PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(2); // new value, say depending on 'beat'
      })
       // Hearthbeat 2
      .progress(function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);
      })
      .fail(function(id, err) {
          console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
      })
      .then(function(id, beat) {
          console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
          return PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(3); // new value, say depending on 'beat'
      })
       // Hearthbeat 3
      .progress(function(msg) {
          console.log(msg);
      })
      .fail(function(id, err) {
          console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
      })
      .done(function(id, beat) {
          console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
      });
      ```

      }

Getting the following:

- Getting a hearthbeat ... 1
- Getting a hearthbeat ... 1
- Getting a hearthbeat ... 1
- got beat 1: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"3/14/2019 3:54:37 PM"}
- got beat 1: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"3/14/2019 3:54:37 PM"}
- got beat 1: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"3/14/2019 3:54:37 PM"}

Comment: Every single one of those callbacks are being attached to the first promise.  The logic is not going to wait until the "next" promise is available to attach itself to it.  That's the whole point of it being "asynchronous"

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. If I nest them all works. Though there was a cleaner way, without nesting (it is better than nesting callbacks anyway...)

Comment: Why not change `testHeartBeatChaining` to accept in the id?  When the first heartbeat pattern finishes, call the method again with the next id.

Comment: I can't in the real app - the ajax calls are different. This was just an example of 3 calls that are async by nature, but depend on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting works as expected. Still, it is cleaner than nesting callbacks.

```
PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(1)
        .progress(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        })
        .fail(function(id, err) {
            console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
        })
        .then(function(id, beat) {
            console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
            PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(2)                     
            .progress(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            })
            .fail(function(id, err) {
                console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
            })
            .then(function(id, beat) {
                console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
                PersoUtils.getHearthBeat(3)
                .progress(function(msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                })
                .fail(function(id, err) {
                    console.log('ERROR while getting beat' + id + ' : ' + err);
                })
                .done(function(id, beat) {
                    console.log('got beat ' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(beat));
                });
                return this;
            });
            return this;
        });
```

The result is:

- Getting a hearthbeat ... 1
- got beat 1: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"523"}
- Getting a hearthbeat ... 2
- got beat 2: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"590"}
- Getting a hearthbeat ... 3
- got beat 3: {"alive":true,"timestamp":"596"}